# C++ simple IO vowel count program

Tags: c++, io, char, while-loop, file-io

```
char ch;
//Get data from user 
cout << "Enter your sentence on one line followed by a # to end it: " << endl;

while (cin >> character && character != '#') 
{
    cin.get(ch); 
    ch = static_cast<char>(toupper(ch));
    outFile << ch;

    if (character == 'A' || character == 'E' || character == 'I' || character == 'O'
                || character == 'U')
    {
        vowelCount ++;

    }
}
outFile << "number of vowels: " << vowelCount << endl;
```

I am trying to input a sentence, read how many vowels, blank spaces, and other characters it has. But the vowelCount is never right and I can't get it to write the same sentence to output file either. Any hints?

Comment: You are already reading into `character`. Why read again in `ch`? Also, you might want to read up what a vowel is and how many there are.

Comment: worse, yet, reading into `character` just skipped leading spaces as well! You only want to use something like `cin.get(ch)`. The other issue is that the argument to `toupper()` has to be a positive integer but `char` can be signed in which case e.g. my name could crash your program. You want to use something like `toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch))`.

Comment: Using `cin >> character` operator reads in one character off the standard input into the character variable.  Doing `cin.get(ch)` reads in a second character into the ch variable.  You only need to do one of these operations.  Delete the `cin.get(ch)` line and try replacing all references to `character` with `ch`.

Comment: when I write to outFile, how can i write say (character) with white spaces as well.

Comment: @mmodahl: your characterization of the behavior of `cin >> character` is only correct if the `noskipws` flag is set (e.g. using `std::cin >> std::noskipws`). Otherwise formatted input of a character skips leading whitespace. This should also answer the question on how to also write whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown the declaration / initialization of the variable `vowelCount`.  I assume you have only declared (and not initialized) it using a statement like:

```
int vowelCount; // notice the variable is not initialized.
```

In C++, `int` variables have no default value.  If you have written such code, you can correct it by explicitly initializing its value with a statement like:

```
int vowelCount = 0;
```

Moreover, your loops reads 2 characters at each iteration (skipping one out of two characters) and you are missing the vowel `Y`.

The corrected example would look like:

```
//Get data from user 
cout << "Enter your sentence on one line followed by a # to end it: " << endl;

int vowelCount = 0;
while (cin >> character && character != '#') 
{
    character = toupper(character);

    if (character == 'A' || character == 'E' || character == 'I' || character == 'O'
                || character == 'U' || character == 'Y')
    {
        vowelCount ++;

    }
}
outFile << "number of vowels: " << vowelCount << endl;
```

Comment: This is slightly misleading considering his next task is to count whitespaces.

Comment: OP can use disable/enable the skipping of whitespace using the [`cin >> noskipws` and `cin >> skipws` manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) or can use the `while (cin.get(character))` syntax instead.

Comment: From Wiki: In writing systems based on the Latin alphabet, the letters A, E, I, O, U, and sometimes Y are all used to represent vowels. 'Y' might be optional for his homework.

Answer (score 0):

Just like pmr's comment indicates, the problem is that you are reading in two characters with each loop iteration, but only checking the first one. Both of these statements consume a character from stdin:

```
cin >> character
...
cin.get(ch)
```

all you need to do is this:

```
while (cin >> character && character != '#') 
{
    character = static_cast<char>(toupper(character));
```

Comment: how would I read white spaces? once I got the vowels, I am stuck on reading white spaces.