# Need to read white space and other chars C++

Tags: c++, io, while-loop, chars

I have been working on this all day with no luck. Its night now and don't know what to do. My assignment is to read number of vowels, number of white spaces, and number of other characters in a user inputted sentence. I know i need to use cin.get(ch) for whitespaces, but don't know how. I also need to output the sentence to a file. Heres what I have so far:

```
//Get data from user 
cout << "Enter your sentence on one line followed by a # to end it: " << endl;



while (cin >> noskipws >> character && character != '#')
{
    character = static_cast<char>(toupper(character));

    if (character == 'A' || character == 'E' || character == 'I' ||
            character == 'O' ||  character == 'U')
    {
        vowelCount++;
        isVowel = true;

    }

    if (isspace(character))
    {
        whiteSpace++;

    }

    else if (isVowel == true && isspace(character))
    {
        otherChars++;
    }

    outFile << character;

}


outFile << "vowelCount: " << vowelCount << endl;
outFile << "whiteSpace: " << whiteSpace << endl;
outFile << "otherchars: " << otherChars << endl;
```

Comment: You should get together with [user1193717](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1193717/user1193717) looks like you are taking the same class. Share ideas and notes, perhaps makes this easier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ simple IO vowel count program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186231/c-simple-io-vowel-count-program)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ch;
    int vowel_count = 0;
    int space_count = 0;
    int other_count = 0;

    cout << "Enter a string ends with #: " << endl;

    while(1)
    {
        cin.get(ch);
        if(ch == '#')
        {
            break;
        }

        if(ch == 'A' || ch == 'a'
            || ch == 'E' || ch == 'e'
            || ch == 'I' || ch == 'i'
            || ch == 'O' || ch == 'o'
            || ch == 'U' || ch == 'u')
        {
            ++vowel_count;
        }
        else if(ch == ' ')
        {
            ++space_count;
        }
        else
        {
            ++other_count;
        }
    }


    cout << "Vowels: " << vowel_count << endl;
    cout << "White spaces: " << space_count << endl;
    cout << "Other: " << other_count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

No arrays

Comment: not allowed to use arrays :( also supposed to test for other characters that are not vowels and white spaces. so Don't know wwhat Im going to do.

Comment: This is so bad to do your homework, wish you are not a programmer

Comment: do u think I am too dumb to be a programmer?

Comment: No, it's because you need to learn how to write programmes, not asking for the code directly. I mean you should try to google how to use cin, etc. BTW: www.cplusplus.com is good.

Comment: @shengy: Then don't provide it. You're only encouraging him and others like him.

Comment: @shengy: BTW **cplusplus.com is *awful***

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit My fault for providing it, why is cplusplus.com awful? is there a better website?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/88241/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources

Answer (score 4):

This line

```
if (character == 'A' || 'E' || 'I' || 'O' || 'U');
```

Is not doing what you think.  It will always return true.

you need

```
if (character == 'A' || character == 'E' || character == 'I' || character == 'O' || character =='U')
```

and remove the semicolon as well at the end of that line

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
while (cin >> character && character != '#')
```

You are skipping all white space. To prevent the operator >> from skiiping white space you need to explicitly specify this with the noskipws modifier.

```
while(std::cin >> std::noskipws >> character && character != '#')
```

Alternatively the same affect can be achieved with get

```
while(std::cin.get(character) && character != '#')
```

Next you are reading more characters outside the loop condition.

```
cin.get(character);
```

You already have a value in the variable 'character'. So remove both of these. The next iteration of the loop (in the while condition) will get the next character (as it is executed before the loop is entered).

Then fix you test as Tim pointed out.
You can then add another test for white space with:

```
if (std::isspace(character)) // Note #include <cctype> 
{  /* STUFF */ }
```

Comment: i edited above. But will this go through and count all white spaces in the sentence? Also how can I get it to print to an outFile text with spaces as well, character by character?

Comment: according to the assignment, I am supposed to use: cin.get(ch) to get the white spaces

Comment: @user1196155: Updated to use cin.get().

Answer (score 0):

You can check for whitespace the exact same way. Common whitespace characters are space (`' '`), and horizontal tab (`'\t'`). Less-common are newline (`'\n'`), carriage return (`'\r'`), form feed (`'\f'`) and vertical tab (`'\v'`).

You can also use `isspace` from `ctype.h`.

Comment: Can you show me how you would do it with ' '? Because I tried this before, and it doesnt tell me all the characters with whitespaces in a sentence.

Comment: according to the assignment, I am supposed to use: cin.get(ch) to get the white spaces

Comment: I don't quite understand what your issue is. Why can't you check for whitespace exactly the same way you check for vowels?

Comment: because the instructions say: To input each character, including the white space (the blanks), you will need to use the get 
function
A. Correct statement to read a variable ch, defined of the type char
cin.get(ch);

Comment: I am supposed to transport whatever a userinputs, into an output text file. But whitespaces don't "transport".

Comment: @user1196155 I don't follow what that has to do with your question. None of the code you pasted does any ouput, and if there's an error in your output code, I'm not sure how we're supposed to find it.

Comment: i edited post again above. I cant include all the code but, I am tryin to count nonvowels, and non spaces or "other characters" as well as the last part of the assignment. the vowels and white spaces work fine now, but not sure how to count othercharacters in the sentence.

Comment: Fix your if/elseif tree. You need an `else if` for all but the first branch, and you need a catchall `else` at the end which would indicate a character that didn't match any of the other branches. (It sounds like you're attempting something more advanced than you are ready for.)